# tooltip function of highcharts through gson in java?

Tags: highcharts, gson

Can some one guide me to make json for tooltip function of highcharts through gson in java?

e.g :

`"formatter": "function(){return defaultTooltipFormatter(this);}",`

I want this like

`"formatter": function(){return defaultTooltipFormatter(this);},`

Comment: Can you add a bit more detail?